# How can I separate a variable using only the specified separator (keeping white space)

Tags: r, tidyverse, separator

I'm looking for a tidyverse solution to separate a variable with values containing white space and `.`

I want to separate by the `.` and keep the parts on either side.

Example

```
library(tidyverse)

Data <- data.frame(Var1 = "A", Var2 = "C and D.E.F")

Data %>%
     separate(Var2, 
        into = c("Var3", "Var4", "Var5"), 
        sep = ".")
```

Gives:

```
  Var1 Var3 Var4 Var5
1    A    C  and    D

Warning message:
Expected 3 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 1 rows [1].
```

So it seems separate is using white space and my specified separator. How can I use only the specified separator?

Desired output is:

```
  Var1   Var3   Var4 Var5
1  A   C and D    E    F
```

Answer (score 0):

Using square brackets provides the correct output:

```
Data %>%
     separate(Var2, 
        into = c("Var3", "Var4", "Var5"), 
        sep = "[.]")

  Var1    Var3 Var4 Var5
1    A C and D    E    F
```